# How come the instance variable inside a Runnable is gone when it's executed?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, threadpool, runnable, threadpoolexecutor

```
@Autowired
ThreadPoolTaskScheduler taskScheduler;

@Autowired
SendUpdatesRunnable sendUpdatesRunnable;

private void createJob(String timezone) {
        ZonedDateTime zoned = LocalDate.now().atTime(10, 11).atZone(ZoneId.of(timezone));
           
        sendUpdatesRunnable.timezone = timezone;
        taskScheduler.schedule(
                sendUpdatesRunnable,
                Date.from(zoned.toInstant())
        );
    }
```

and

```
@Component
public class SendUpdatesRunnable implements Runnable{

    @Autowired
    ProductRepository productRepository;

    String timezone;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void run() {
        List<Product> newProds = productRepository.findProductByCreateDateTimeIsAfter(LocalDateTime.now().minusHours(24));
        List<Product> updatedProds = productRepository.findProductByUpdateDateTimeIsAfter(LocalDateTime.now().minusHours(24));

       //System print out timezone variable = null
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what you're asking? What do you expect? What happens, when and how?

Answer (score 0):

### Problem

When you inject a Spring Bean with AOP stuff (i.e. `@Transcational`) Spring Framework doesn't inject the real concrete class, but instead a proxy object. The proxy class holds the field `timezone` and it doesn't get delegated to your real class instance.

How Proxies in Spring Framework work:

[image: How Proxies work]

[source](https://spring.io/blog/2012/05/23/transactions-caching-and-aop-understanding-proxy-usage-in-spring)

The proxy exists because your `run()` method would look something like this:

```
public void run() {
  transactionManager.begin();
  realInstance.run();
  transactionManager.commit();
}
```

So when you set timezone like this `sendUpdatesRunnable.timezone = timezone;` it is actually doing this `proxy.timezone = timezone;` and your `sendUpdatesRunnable` object still has `timezone` as null.

### Solution

You need to use getters/setters.

When you use a setter method, the proxy class will have an implementation of it like this:

```
public void setTimezone(String timezone) {
  realInstance.setTimezone(timezone);
}
```

Thus, when you call the set method, it will propagate properly to the real instance where the concrete implementation is.

With that said, you shouldn't be using instance level mutable variables at all in Spring Bean implementations. The only instance variables you should have are dependencies that are injected at bean initialization.

Comment: I mean non dependency instance variables. I'll update to clarify.